# Add parameters to internal wordpress links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add query parameters to all internal links inside a wordpress blog.

for example-
client lands on the blog with this link:

```
www.example.com/?p1=test&p2=test
```

I want the links inside the blog, for example a link to a post, to still have the query strings:

```
www.example.com/post1/?p1=test&p2=test
```

Is there is a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using `add_query_arg( 'Key', 'value', 'url' );`
For more information visit this link
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Comment: Thanks @Rahi , can you please give an example/explanation how to use it?

Comment: suppose you wan to add 2 extra parameter  single blog page url ( on click read more button ) like  http://localhost/clinica/2017/02/24/hello-world/?p1=test&p2=test  .  Code Example :     
<?php 
    $perm = array(
      'p1' => 'test',
      'p2' => 'test'
    );
    ?>
    
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( $perm, get_the_permalink() ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'textdomain' ); ?></a>

see screenshot below
http://prntscr.com/elii1l
http://prntscr.com/eliils